# What kind of critical point is (0,0) in $f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2)^2 - 3x(x^2+y^2) +2x^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have to determine whether the point (0,0) is maximum, minimum or saddle in $f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2)^2 - 3x(x^2+y^2) +2x^2$

I've tried the "Second derivative test" and the "Perfect square form" but none of them works here!

I also entered the function in Wolfram-alpha and tho (0,0) is considered a critical point of the function it's neither maximum, minimum or saddle. which is not possible.

I checked the 3D graph and (0,0) looks like a minimum.

could you please help me determine and show what kind of critical point (0,0) is?

thanks a lot.

Comment: Since
$$x^3 = o(x^2), \\
x^4 = o(x^2), \\
x^2 y^2 = o(x y^2),$$
the leading terms in the expansion of $f$ around the origin are
$$2 x^2 - 3 x y^2 + y^4 =
(x - y^2) (2 x - y^2).$$
Now consider paths of the form $x = \alpha y^2$ to show that $f$ has neither a local maximum nor a local minimum at the origin.

Comment: @Maxim what’s $o(x^2)$ ? Doesn’t look familiar to me!

Comment: @Peter Foreman thank you!

Comment: $o(x^2)$ is a quantity which is [asymptotically smaller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation) than $x^2$ (as $(x, y) \to (0, 0)$).